# Angular app constantly increases heap memory

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to analyze my Angular app performance. App getting slower over a time of usage(when navigating between pages or simply leave tab opened for some time). Thus I have captured performance record over a time. And seems like memory leaks are present here. It tells that memory increasing in parallel with increasing of number of Nodes(see Nodes graph) however Listeners are getting garbage collected. Could somebody tell me what is Nodes graph certainly means? What are possible reasons of this mysterious Nodes increasing in Angular[image]

Comment: Are you use unsubscribe on component destroy to your subscribers ?

Comment: Yeap, incorrect unsubscribing is the most common memory leaks reason, so i have checked it multiple times in every component before ask here

Comment: Also u can see listeners getting dropped on charts. I guess it means that unsubscribing is correct

Comment: I am also facing same issue, any luck with this?
I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527515/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-angular